# Unable to install 'tesserocr' using pip3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.x, cython, tesseract, ubuntu-16.04, python-tesseract

I am trying to install the 'tesserocr' module for python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 using the command

`pip3 install tesserocr --user`

OR

`sudo pip3 install tesserocr`

I have already installed Tesseract 3.04 and Leptonica 1.73 using:

`sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr libtesseract-dev libleptonica-dev`

For some reason Cython is generating a compiler error when I try to install 'tesserocr'

```
daksh@daksh-linux:~/tesser/tesseract$ sudo pip3 install tesserocr
[sudo] password for daksh: 
The directory '/home/daksh/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/daksh/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting tesserocr
  Downloading tesserocr-2.1.2.tar.gz (47kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.6MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/tesserocr.egg-info
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/tesserocr.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/tesserocr.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/tesserocr.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/tesserocr.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    Supporting tesseract v3.04.01
    Configs from pkg-config: {'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 197633}, 'libraries': ['tesseract', 'lept'], 'include_dirs': ['/usr/include']}

    Error compiling Cython file:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ...
                bool b
                bool font_info
                TessResultRenderer *temp
                TessResultRenderer *renderer = NULL

            IF TESSERACT_VERSION >= 0x030401:
                                ^
    ------------------------------------------------------------

    tesserocr.pyx:1862:29: Compile-time name 'TESSERACT_VERSION' not defined

    Error compiling Cython file:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ...
                bool b
                bool font_info
                TessResultRenderer *temp
                TessResultRenderer *renderer = NULL

            IF TESSERACT_VERSION >= 0x030401:
                                ^
    ------------------------------------------------------------

    tesserocr.pyx:1862:29: Error in compile-time expression: TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= int()

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-jnh9jb37/tesserocr/setup.py", line 166, in <module>
        test_suite='tests'
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 186, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 209, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 293, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 322, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 132, in add_defaults
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 19, in finalize_options
        self.distribution.ext_modules)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 925, in cythonize
        cythonize_one(*args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1047, in cythonize_one
        raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
    Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: tesserocr.pyx
    Compiling tesserocr.pyx because it changed.
    [1/1] Cythonizing tesserocr.pyx

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jnh9jb37/tesserocr/
```

I don't understand why this is happening! :/

Comment: `TESSERACT_VERSION` is a cython compile-time variable but for some reason it's not working in your case. You could possibly have an outdated version of Cython, try upgrading it and then re-install tesserocr.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by upgrading pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```